# Why does windows authentication prompting credentials popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

I am using windows authentication for my intranet application which was developed in ASP.NET MVC 4.0.

In Web.config file, i set authentication mode="Windows" and in IIS Enabled Windows Authentication and disabled Ananymous and impersonation is disabled.

Everythng working fine in local, but when i deployed it to windows server 2012 using IIS 8.5 it was prompting credentials popup for first time page load. even if i enter correct credentials its not worked. then i clicked cancel for 3 to 4 times page loaded without issues. If i close the browser and reloads the same url its not asked for credentials. after sometime used the same url this time its asked for credentials.

This issue is happening randomly and am able to reproduce the issue when i refresh the page continuously for 10-15 times.am using IE 11 and google chrome browsers.in both browsers same issue.

As per my requirement it should not display the popup for credentials as it is a intranet application.

Please help me on this, i was trying to fix from last two weeks but no solution yet.

Comment: get with your network admin perhaps on the remote server your `domain\user` does not have rights / authorization do you have a systems / network admin..?

Comment: I do reply to your ASP.NET forum duplicate post for the same issue. You did not yet collect all the required data, so further troubleshooting is still mandate on your side.

Comment: I really really really suggest you switch to NTLM instead of "Windows" (really Kerberos) authentication. If you MUST use Kerberos, you could contract me at my hourly rate to fix the issue...Kerberos is an evil hell spawn to debug...

Answer (score 1):

We were just working on this exact issue. It appears that a Windows update caused this issue. We were seeing problems in Exchange Web Services, Autodiscover, LDAPS, basically anything that touched IIS.

The KB is: KB3179575. We also removed KB3177723 just in case.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, that generally happens when *authorization* fails. The user is authenticated, because they are logged into their machine, but they are not in a required role or are otherwise not authorized to view the resource. The popup is a chance to switch to an account that does have access.

Comment: It can be, if IIS log files do show 401.3 for such access, but so far no evidence from the questioner to prove that.